# Calculating a value for a current row in a dataframe using subset in R

Tags: r, dataframe, calculation

I need to calculate some intermediate calculations using R.
Here is the data about some events and their types during some years.

```
structure(list(year = c(1994, 1995, 1997, 1997, 1998, 1998, 1998, 
2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2002), N = c(3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L), type = c("OIL", "LNG", "AGS", "OIL", 
"DOCK", "LNG", "OIL", "LNG", "OIL", "LNG", "OIL", "DOCK")), .Names =     c("year", 
"N", "type"), row.names = c(NA, 12L), class = "data.frame")


> head(mydf3)
  year N type
1 1994 3  OIL
2 1995 1  LNG
3 1997 1  AGS
4 1997 4  OIL
5 1998 1 DOCK
6 1998 1  LNG
```

I need to get the data about cumulative sum of N by Year and type, total cumulative sum this year and cumulative sum for year until current for all types.

So i need to get information like this

```
year type cntyear cnt_cumultype cnt_cumulalltypes
1994 OIL 3 3 3
1994 LNG 0 0 3
1994 AGS 0 0 3
1994 DOCK 0 0 3
1995 OIL 0 3 4
1995 LNG 1 1 4
1995 AGS 0 0 4
1995 DOCK 0 0 4
...
```

Some explanation:

1. cntyear - this is N count for current year and type.
2. cnt_cumultype - this is cumulative sum for this type until current year.
3. cnt_cumulalltypes - this is cumulative sum for all types for all
   years including current <=current year.

Just wanted to do something like this, but it didn't worked right...

```
mydf3$cnt_cumultype<-tail(cumsum(mydf3[which(mydf3$type==mydf3$type & mydf3$year==mydf3$year),]$N), n=1)
```

How to calculate this numbers by rows?

Comment: Please spend some time explaining the calculation of your three new variables. Your desired output is not sufficient to distinguish them (for me at least).

Comment: done, add some explanation

Comment: So, in your desired output, shouldn't 1995 oil be 3 for cnt_cumultype?

Comment: yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with the `data.table` package. This is also possible to solve in base R, but one step in particular is shorter with `data.table`.

```
# load library
library(data.table)
# caste df as a data.table and change column order
setcolorder(setDT(df), c("year", "type", "N"))
# change column names
setnames(df, names(df), c("year", "type", "cntyear"))

# get all type-year combinations in data.table with `CJ` and join these to original
# then, in second [, replace all observations with missing counts to 0
df2 <- df[CJ("year"=unique(df$year), "type"=unique(df$type)), on=c("year", "type")
          ][is.na(cntyear),  cntyear := 0]
# get cumulative counts for each type
df2[, cnt_cumultype := cumsum(cntyear), by=type]
# get total counts for each year
df2[, cnt_cumulalltypes := cumsum(cntyear)]
```

This results in

```
df2
    year type cntyear cnt_cumultype cnt_cumulalltypes
 1: 1994  AGS       0             0                 0
 2: 1994 DOCK       0             0                 0
 3: 1994  LNG       0             0                 0
 4: 1994  OIL       3             3                 3
 5: 1995  AGS       0             0                 3
 6: 1995 DOCK       0             0                 3
 7: 1995  LNG       1             1                 4
 8: 1995  OIL       0             3                 4
 9: 1997  AGS       1             1                 5
    ....
```

Comment: thank's, i will try. there is one more question, how to calc cnt_cumulalltypes - it must be calculated for all years until current. e.g. for 1995 - the total sum of all years <=1995 must be calculated.